# Class number parity for certain CM fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am interested in knowing the parity of the class number of a number field of the shape $L = K(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity and $K$ is a totally real field (of class number one). Are there any known criteria on $K$ under which the class number of $L$ is even?

Does anyone know of references related to this question? It looks like P.E. Conner and J. Hurrelbrink's book "Class Number Parity" might have something related to this, but I wasn't able to find an electronic/hard copy of it.

Comment: You can try to look at H. Ichimura, _Refined version of Hass'es Satz 45 on class number parity_, Tsukuba J. Math, Vol. 38 No. 2 (2014), 189–199. What is more or less clear is that information on the _narrow_ class number of $K$ is more relevant than the "usual" class number: if the narrow class number is $1$ and there is a unique prime above $3$ in $K$, for instance, then $2\nmid h_L$ as in Theorem 10.4b of Washington's _Introduction to cyclotomic fields_